# Retrieve previous days data (PHP script), and send data using Amazon SNS

Tags: php, amazon-sns

I have a piece of code that will display the results and comparisons of a number(3) of database queries in a browser. It displays the differences in the figures of each DB. It works and that is all okay. Now, what I have to do is forget about the webpage and have the php script run once a day, say at 3am, and the script has to look for any difference in the DB figures for the previous day. If any differences are discovered, using Amazon Simple Notifications Service, an email will be sent to all the subscribers with the details those differences. Here is the part of my code that is new from the previous working script (the one for the browser):

```
if ($total_results) {
    foreach ($total_results as $cid => $dates) {

        foreach($dates as $row) {        
        $dbOne_total = $row['dbOne_total'];
        $dbTwo_total = $row['dbTwo_total'];
        $dbThree_total = $row['dbThree_total'];
        $difference = ($dbTwo_total - $dbOne_total);
        $difference_bill = ($dbThree_total - $dbOne_total);


        $mismatchFile = fopen("mismatch.txt", "w");
        $issue = "";
        while($startDate == date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'))) {
            if (($difference_bill > 0) || ($difference > 0)) {
                $issue = ($row["company"] ." ". $row["company_id"]. " ". "dbTwo Difference". " ". $difference. " "."dbThree Difference". " ". $difference_bill);
                print_r($issue);
                topic("DATABASE-MISMATCH")->send("List of mismatches between databases", "Issue:  $issue/n"); // for ASN

            }
         }
        fwrite($mismatchFile, $issue);
        fclose($mismatchFile);
    }
}
```

$startDate is a variable I am using throughout the code as I have sql queries running that need this date to get the info.
I'm questioning this line:

```
while($startDate == date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'))) {
```

I'm not sure if strtotime is the best option (I'm worried about possible format issues). Is there a better way to get the data from the previous day?

I'm wondering if I am approaching this problem in the correct way? I would also appreciate any advice on how to the $issue variable into the Amazon SNS email body, as a list, or would it be better to create a file and send that as an attachment?

I am still quite a newbie to PHP and so any assistance, or a helpful point in the right direction, would be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`while($startDate == date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')))` is a wrong approach. It always returns `true` and the cycle is infinite.

If you want just a one time `day before`, use

```
$date = new \DateTime('now - 1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

If you need to do it in a loop

```
$date = new \DateTime(); // now here
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $date->sub(new \DateInterval('P' . $i . 'D'); // $i days before, $i>0
}
```